# Changing values in a column with values from another vector based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

Imagine I have this df.

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
df <- data.frame("item" = 1:10, "quantity" = c(21,15,12,14,26,12,13,15,24,26), "value" = c(90,110,105,102,86,112,75,84,34,99))
```

Ideally I'd like to max out values at 100. Therefore, I want to take any item that has a value above 95 and then scale them in a 1:5 range. Then I'd like to add that scaled values on top of 95 to get values that are between 95 and 100. Here is what I currently have:

```
x <- df[df$value >= 95,]
x <- x$value
x <- rescale(x, to = c(0,5))
x  # [1] 4.23, 2.31, 1.15, 5.00, 0.00
df <- df %>% mutate(value = ifelse(value >= 95, 95 + x, value))
```

This gives me `95+x[1]` for all values that are above 95 as you can imagine. I think I'm in need of a for loop but couldn't quite figure out how to structure it. Thanks.

The desired output would be:

```
Item Quantity Value
1       21    90 
2       15    99.23
3       12    97.31
4       14    96.15
5       26    86 
6       12    100
7       13    75 
8       15    84
9       24    34 
10      26    95
```

Comment: Thank you @N. Williams and @H 1, I'm still getting a uniform change for some reason. I'm sure its something wrong on my end and nothing to do with your answers so thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but using dplyr and the scales package:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(Value = ifelse(Value >= 95, 95 + scales::rescale(Value, to = c(1, 5)), Value))
```

Edit:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Value >= 95) %>% 
  mutate(Value = 95 + scales::rescale(Value, to = c(0, 5))) %>% 
  bind_rows(filter(df, Value < 95)) %>% 
  arrange(Item)
```

Comment: Close but this again creates a uniform change instead of adding the scale of  each value individually

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with a simple subset in *base r*:

```r
df <- data.frame("item" = 1:10, 
                 "quantity" = c(21,15,12,14,26,12,13,15,24,26),
                 "value" = c(90,110,105,102,86,112,75,84,34,99))

df[df$value >= 95,"value"] <- 95 + scales::rescale(df[df$value >= 95,"value"], to=c(0, 5))

df
#>    item quantity     value
#> 1     1       21  90.00000
#> 2     2       15  99.23077
#> 3     3       12  97.30769
#> 4     4       14  96.15385
#> 5     5       26  86.00000
#> 6     6       12 100.00000
#> 7     7       13  75.00000
#> 8     8       15  84.00000
#> 9     9       24  34.00000
#> 10   10       26  95.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not completely certain I've grasped the expected output, but possibly something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = Value >= 95) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = ifelse(Value >= 95, 95 + ntile(Value, 5), Value))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   grp [2]
    Item Quantity Value grp   New_Value
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>
 1     1       21    90 FALSE        90
 2     2       15   110 TRUE         99
 3     3       12   105 TRUE         98
 4     4       14   102 TRUE         97
 5     5       26    86 FALSE        86
 6     6       12   112 TRUE        100
 7     7       13    75 FALSE        75
 8     8       15    84 FALSE        84
 9     9       24    34 FALSE        34
10    10       26    99 TRUE         96
```

Or same approach but using `scales::rescale()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp = Value >= 95) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = ifelse(Value >= 95, 95 + scales::rescale(Value, c(0,5)), Value))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   grp [2]
    Item Quantity Value grp   New_Value
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>
 1     1       21    90 FALSE      90  
 2     2       15   110 TRUE       99.2
 3     3       12   105 TRUE       97.3
 4     4       14   102 TRUE       96.2
 5     5       26    86 FALSE      86  
 6     6       12   112 TRUE      100  
 7     7       13    75 FALSE      75  
 8     8       15    84 FALSE      84  
 9     9       24    34 FALSE      34  
10    10       26    99 TRUE       95
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in data.table, but here's how I would have done it

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("Item" = 1:10,
                 "Quantity" = c(21,15,12,14,26,12,13,15,24,26),
                 "Value" = c(90,110,105,102,86,112,75,84,34,99))

dt[Value >= 95, Value := 95 + (Value - 95) / (max(Value) - 95) * 5]
```

Also in base

```
df <- data.frame("Item" = 1:10,
                 "Quantity" = c(21,15,12,14,26,12,13,15,24,26),
                 "Value" = c(90,110,105,102,86,112,75,84,34,99))

x <- df[df$Value >= 95, "Value"] - 95
df[df$Value >= 95, "Value"] <- 95 + x / max(x) * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked:

```
x <- df[df$value >= 95,]
x <- x$value
x <- rescale(x, to = c(0,5))
x  # [1] 4.23, 2.31, 1.15, 5.00, 0.00
df$Value[df$Value>95] <- 95 + x
```